# How to measure raspberry pi energy consumption through programs

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-4, python-3

Is any Device available in the market that can measure the raspberry pi energy consumption and has a mechanism to read that information from my own program?

I explored the specifications of USB meter and Wall meters, they display the information on their LCD displays. Have not found anything that has the option to send that information back to the raspberry pi.

A few USB Power Meters come with Bluetooth such as https://www.amazon.ca/MakerHawk-Bluetooth-Current-24-000V-Multimeter/dp/B07C9DQ4F9. Is it possible to get the power measured by the device over BlueTooth by writing my own Bluetooth program?

Comment: Is there something else you are expecting in terms of an answer to your question? If so, please edit your question; if not please [read this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

[IN219 current sensor breakout](https://www.adafruit.com/product/904) might be a option. you basically insert this where with want to measure the current, usually the power to the Rasberry pi.  It connects to the PI with I2C. should meet what you want.

You can carefully split the usb power cord open cut the red wire and attach it to the board. You need a soldering iron and some hook up wire but it's a solid solution and there are libraries availble.

Comment: Thank you for the response. What about USB Power Meters with Bluetooth such as https://www.amazon.ca/MakerHawk-Bluetooth-Current-24-000V-Multimeter/dp/B07C9DQ4F9. Is it possible to get the power measured by the device over bluetooth by writing my own program?

Comment: @SAROJPANDA It seems like that uses the Serial Port Profile. this usually manifests as a COMM Port. You'd then have to figure out what all the data means. If you're lucky it's simple text.  I have a DMM that serial data is the current lighting for the 7digit display,  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91cdAuGcMWL._SL1500_.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Yes - there is a world of test instruments in the market that are capable of measuring current, voltage and time (Energy = V * I * t) consumed by a Raspberry Pi. Here's [one example of such an instrument](https://www.fluke.com/en-us/product/electrical-testing/digital-multimeters/fluke-287), and you can find many others by searching the Internet.

You asked about using the GPIO for this measurement. That is rather vague, and would likely be awkward under any set of circumstances, but if you care to edit your question to refine what you had in mind by using GPIO, perhaps you'll get a better answer.

WRT your revised question:

> A few USB Power Meters come with Bluetooth - [for example](https://www.amazon.ca/MakerHawk-Bluetooth-Current-24-000V-Multimeter/dp/B07C9DQ4F9). Is it possible to get the power measured by the device over BlueTooth by writing my own Bluetooth program?

Possible? **Yes, *probably***. Straightforward? **Probably not.** If you'll take the time to actually read the [manufacturer's information](http://www.mediafire.com/file/tzgfyra5r707efp/um25%2528c%2529_usb_tester_meter__instruction_%252B_pc_software_intruction%252B_android_app_instruction-_3_in_1_-__2019.9.26.pdf/file) from the Amazon site, it *suggests* that they **do not** publish an API or any specifications that you could use to write your own program.

But the real answer to your question is only available from the manufacturer. I would suggest you post a question about the product on the Amazon website. **If** the manufacturer provides an "Open" API, then it is likely you can get the measurement data through a program you write. If they don't, you may still be able to get it, but you will have to hack it by studying raw Bluetooth data sent between the device and one of their supported apps (this is likely to require a lot of work).

Comment: Thank you for the response. What about USB Power Meters with Bluetooth such as https://www.amazon.ca/MakerHawk-Bluetooth-Current-24-000V-Multimeter/dp/B07C9DQ4F9. Is it possible to get the power measured by the device over bluetooth by writing my own program?

Comment: That depends entirely upon what data is **available** over the Bluetooth interface. As typical, Amazon's "junk factories" supply no specifications or details. You might try asking a question on Amazon... There's no doubt this measurement **can be made**, but it's a "shopping effort" to find the instrument that meets your price and features requirements.